# Finding mean of character value (grouping by another variable)

Tags: r

I'm having some issues of finding the mean of a character variable (grouping by another variable).

In the example data below, how would I find the mean of `Apple`, grouped by `Class`?

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Class = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
    Fruit = c("Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Apple", "Banana", 
    "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the proportion of 'Apple', use `mean` on a logical vector

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   reframe(prop_apple = mean(Fruit == 'Apple'), .by = 'Class')
```

-output

```
   Class prop_apple
1     1        0.4
2     0        0.5
```

---

Or for previous versions

```
df %>%
   group_by(Class) %>%
   summarise(prop_apple = mean(Fruit == "Apple"), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Class prop_apple
  <int>      <dbl>
1     0        0.5
2     1        0.4
```

Comment: Thank you, though I have dplyr installed I get the following error message:

`Error in reframe(., prop_apple = mean(Fruit == "Apple"), .by = "Class") : 
  could not find function "reframe"`

Comment: @Jamie i updated wiht previous version code